# pip install django - Deprecation

Tags: django, pip

Quiero actualizar la versión de django que estoy utilizando ya que me arroja que algunos de mis procesos necesitan una versión mayor a la 1.11 del mismo, pero al intentar actualizar la versión con el comando

```
pip install django
```

Me arroja lo siguiente

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st,
>   2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python
>   2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support

Comment: Es python2 el que da problemas si cambias a python3 probablemente tendrás otros problemas

Comment: No puedo actualizar el python porque el programa que estoy utilizando en su ultima versión necesita como base python 2.7. alguna otra idea ? de como hacer un bypass de pip para forzar  el upgrade de django?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el error esta también en la versión que tienes instalada de Python. Intenta primero actualizar la versión de Python y luego actualiza la versión de Django.

Te  recomiendo revisar [este enlace](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/faq/install/#what-python-version-can-i-use-with-django) para que tengas una mayor idea sobre la versión que necesitas de ambos, aunque lo mejor es tener la versión más estable de ambos.

Comment: La verdad es que hay un tema con la versión y es que no permite hacer actualizaciones por que está pronta a perder la mantención, finalmente tuve que entrar a los archivos de la librería de django en python y cambiar la versión a mano.